# Remover item de lista baseado em valor de propriedade

Tags: c#

Tenho uma lista de objetos, os objetos tem a seguintes propriedades

```
public class oItem {
    public decimal nit_codit { get; set; }
    ... etc
}
```

Então tenho a lista de objetos

```
List<oItem> PlItens = new List<oItem>();
```

Supanhamos que a lista foi carregada com n registros, eu quero remover da lista, os objetos cujo a propriedade nit_codit seja 0..

Tentei:

```
if (PlItens.Exists(x => x.nit_codit == 0)) {
     PlItens.Remove(x);
}
```

E também:

```
PlItens.Remove(x => x.nit_codit == 0);
```

Mas pelo jeito não é desta maneira.. alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Estás a tentar remover uma lista de dados e não apenas um dado, certo?

Comment: Estavas quase @William a segunda forma era so completar o remove All.

Comment: Obrigado a todas as respostas, deu certo com a solução do @DiegoSantos, mais uma vez, agradeço todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
 PlItens.RemoveAll(x => x.nit_codit == 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Dessa primeira forma que você tentou:

```
if (PlItens.Exists(x => x.nit_codit == 0)) {
    PlItens.Remove(x);
}
```

Não funciona porque "x" não existe na linha onde você tem `PlItens.Remove(x);`, ele apenas pertence ao escopo da expressão lambda dentro do método Exists.

Dessa segunda forma que você usou o método Remove, você precisaria passar um objeto oItem para ser removido, então tente usar o método ***RemoveAll*** pois ele permite filtrar os elementos:

```
 PlItens.RemoveAll(x => x.nit_codit == 0);
```

Você também pode fazer de outras maneiras, usando [***Linq***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx) por exemplo:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Linq;

//Cria a lista
List<oItem> PlItens = new List<oItem>();

//Cria itens para adicionar na lista
oItem item1 = new oItem(){nit_codit = 0};
oItem item2 = new oItem(){nit_codit = 1};

//Adiciona os itens na lista
PlItens.Add(item1);
PlItens.Add(item2);

//Obtem os objetos cujo a propriedade nit_codit seja 0
var itensIgualAzero = from i in PlItens.ToList() where i.nit_codit == 0 select i;

foreach (var i in itensIgualAzero)
{
    PlItens.Remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que me parece, queres remover uma lista de objetos onde `x => x.nit_codit == 0`, então tens de usar o `RemoveAll` para remover uma lista de dados:

```
PlItens.RemoveAll(PlItens.Where(x => x.nit_codit == 0));
```